# Using Thionyl Chloride with tertiary alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution, intramolecular-reaction

I have a question regarding using $\ce{SOCl2}$ to convert an alcohol into a alkyl halide.
The Klein book mentions that $\ce{SOCl2}$ is only used for primary and secondary alcohol; however, in the solutions for one of their problems (Klein), it uses $\ce{SOCl2}$ to convert tertiary alcohol into an alkyl halide.

[image]

Is it even possible to use $\ce{SOCl2}$ with tertiary alcohol?

Comment: This is not $\mathrm{S_N1}$ or $\mathrm{S_N2}$. This follows $\mathrm{S_N i}$ mechanism. Implying, carbocation formation is absent.

Comment: In future please use $\LaTeX$ environments for formatting. Chemical formulae are written in the `$\ce{}$` environment. Refer to the edited version (and of course Community Wiki) for more details.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNi - Refer.

Answer (score 7):

There is no real barrier against thionyl chloride reacting with a tertiary alcohol. The mechanism described by [Ouellette and Rawn[1]](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-812838-1.50016-5) does not depend on cleavage of a carbon-hydrogen bond and is even illustrated with a tertiary alcohol substrate.

Hydrogen chloride as the electrophilic reagent may provide a good alternative  with tertiary alcohols because this alternative can proceed through a relatively stable tertiary carbocation (the thionyl chloride reaction does not form a carbocation). Carbocation formation would be more difficult with a primary or secondary alcohol.

**Reference**

1. Robert J. Ouellette, J. David Rawn,
   "16 - Alcohols: Reactions and Synthesis", Editor(s): Robert J. Ouellette, J. David Rawn,
   *Organic Chemistry* (Second Edition),
   Academic Press, 2018,
   Pages 463-505, ISBN 9780128128381,
   https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-812838-1.50016-5.